# Undo git push which duplicated all commits

Tags: git

I made a mistake and pulled instead of force pushed and now all my commits are duplicated.
[image: Likes this]
When i use `git rebase -i HEAD~2` I can see a list of all the commits (only once) that shouldn't be there.

Example:

```
pick eefc660 Update sqlconnector.py
pick 7ff4828 Update help to point to correct command
pick 10e6e08 Fix typo
pick 6759aaa Make prefix show properly

# Rebase von 6dde978..4a77d5e auf 6cc7de0 (474 Kommandos)
```

Now my question is can I just comment out those commits or change pick to drop.
Or will this break something?

Answer (score 0):

Updated Answer (Based on the discussion)

```
# Remove files from the index (actual files will stay on disk)
git rm -r --cached .

# Add to the Staging Area
git add .

# finally commit
git commit -m "Files removed to respect the .gitignore"
```

Okay, there are few things happening here.

1. It does not seems to me the commits are duplicate. (check the commit hash they are unique). May be you are thinking they are same because of their commit message.    That's why its always good to use [Git best practices](https://acompiler.com/git-best-practices/) while committing your changes.
2. You are doing interactive Git rebase. So you can can squash your commits. In this case you can change pick to squash. that's it

Comment: All the "duplicated commits" actually have a different hash.
Would this change anything or can I still use squash?

Comment: Did you rebase commits that you have pushed to your repo ?

Comment: Also if you have already pushed your commits, they'll duplicate. You can Force push your branch on the rebased head. It should fix this.

Comment: I just wanted to remove a file that I added to my .gitignore which was already on github. But I made a error as described in my question as I am a beginner with git.

Comment: I just update the answer, that will help you.